# How to decode a large bytes synchronously (excel file)

Tags: flutter, dart, decode, import-from-excel

I am using [excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel) package version [2.0.0-null-safety-3](https://pub.dev/packages/excel/versions/2.0.0-null-safety-3) to read an excel file,

For small files, it looks good

But when reading a **large file**, the interface **stops** until the file is read

```
Excel.decodeBytes(_bytes);
```

> decodeBytes method => sync is not supported

Is there a way to make the process synchronous

To be able to show the (download bar or waiting dialog) to the user

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Compute** For Large Bytes of Data

```
await compute(function,param)
```

[Flutter Compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html)